# Why won't it let me perform this class assignment using generics?

Tags: java, generics, wildcard

I have a classes defined as so:

```
public abstract class AbstractUploadField<T> {
```

And

```
public class GroupField<T> extends AbstractUploadField<T> {
```

Then in Java I am trying to use generics to make sure a class is a subclass of AbstractUploadField

```
Class<? extends AbstractUploadField<?>> clazz = GroupField.class
```

The above does not compile, but if I remove the second wildcard it does:

```
Class<? extends AbstractUploadField> clazz = GroupField.class
```

I don't understand why the first assignment wouldn't work

Comment: Also, is `instanceof AbstractUploadField` not sufficient?

Comment: Cannot convert from Class<GroupField> to Class<? extends AbstractUploadField<?>>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GroupField` and `AbstractUploadField` should both have the same generic type `T`

**In the line**

```
Class<? extends AbstractUploadField<?>> clazz = GroupField.class
```

The first wildcard can be different from the second wildcard which contradicts the first statement.

**The statement:**

```
Class<? extends AbstractUploadField> clazz = GroupField.class
```

works but I assusme you are getting a warning for it.

Comment: I don't follow, the first wildcard would allow any class with AbstractUploadField as a superType.  The second wildcard allows any object type.  Do you mean the AbstractUploadField subtype can infer a different upper bound to object?  I don't see why this would not allow GroupField.class